# MySQL compute percent change

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am new in MySQL.. I want to compute for the percent change of this table using MySQL. Can you help me with the script? I am using 10.3.8-MariaDB MariaDB Server.. Thanks..

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `Column` VARCHAR(14),
  `Amount` VARCHAR(6);

INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`Column`, `Amount`) 
VALUES (`Column 1`, `500`),(`Column 2`, `100`),(`Column 3`, `1100`);
```

I want to get an output table sorted by Column:

```
Column   | Amount | Previous Amount         | Percent Change
Column 1 | 500    | 0                       | ((500-0)/0)*100
Column 2 | 100    | 500 (amount in column1) | ((100-500)/500)*100
Column 3 | 1100   | 100 (amount in column2) | ((1100-100)/100)*100
```

Comment: If you want the term "previous" to exist for your data you MUST determine the sorting order. For example, it can be ``ORDER BY `Column` ASC``. Specify it in your question text (use "edit" link under your question).

Comment: Well. Now please specify your server version - the solutions for 8+ and for 5+ versions are absolutely different.

Comment: I am using 10.3.8-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Comment: Specify this fact in your question and in its tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `Column`,
       Amount,
       COALESCE(LAG(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY `Column` ASC), 0) `Previous Amount`,
       COALESCE(100*(Amount -
                 LAG(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY `Column` ASC)) /
                 LAG(Amount) OVER (ORDER BY `Column` ASC), 0) `Percent Change`
FROM MyTable ;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=87dcf382ee8e214990ff30d075959e5e)

PS. It's extremely bad practice to store number data in VARCHAR field.

PPS. While using any ticks always look for a proper tick type.

Comment: with previous_amount as (
select Column1, Year, Quarter, Amount,
(lag (Amount, 1) over (
 partition by Column1
     order by Column1
)) as prev_amount
from table1
order by Column1, Year, Quarter
)
select Column1, Year, Quarter, prev_amount, Amount,
case
when prev_amount = null then null
when prev_amount = 0 then null
    when prev_amount > 0 then round((((Amount- prev_amount) / prev_amount) * 100)::numeric, 1)
end as percent_change
from previous_amount;

Comment: @CarloKarganilla Of course you may use CTE... it will not alter the fact that you use LAG() for to obtain previous record data. But I'm not sure you need PARTITION clause...

Comment: Thanks. I am using that command in Postgresql but I am not sure why cant be in MySQL.. Although, your command gives me what I need.. I am just curious with the command in Postgres.. Please help me..

Comment: @CarloKarganilla Each DBMS (moreover - each version branch of each DBMS) have its own syntax, features, etc... Of course, the base is similar - but the base only. In most cases the code transferred from one DBMS to another is to be adapted to the last one - excluding the most simple cases maybe.